# How to create a login_required function

Tags: python, flask

I am a new-ish to Flask, and I am trying to create a login_required decorated function for my web app. I would like to make use of session for a user that logs in, which is then cleared once the user logs out.

The session for the user is created like this:

```
# Creates a session for the users and remembers them.
session['username'] = request.form.get("username")
flash("Logged in!")
```

Has anyone got any suggestions to create a good login_required decorated function so that users can only access the web-page when logged in?

Thank you.

P.S I saw (and tried) this as a solution (see below) but I received a "working out of request context" error:

```
def login_required(f):
"""
Decorate routes to require login.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/
"""
@wraps(f)
def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'username'not in session:
        return redirect("/login")
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
return decorated_function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice package for this called [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Example:

```
from flask_login import login_required

@app.route('/my_posts')
@login_required
def my_posts():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how exactly does this decorated function work? (since its from a flask module that i cant find, can you explain it?)

Comment: Your can read about the package [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Install via `pip install flask-login`. In the login route you have to include `login_user(user)` and in the logout route `logout_user()` and then use `@login_required` for each route you only allow logged in users

Comment: Here is a good example: [https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/auth/views.py](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/auth/views.py)